# JPQL (HQL) use parameter of type Map in query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a `HashMap<String, Float> paramMap`

Where the key is the id of entity **Invoice** and the value is some calculation.

JPA allowes this map to be set as a parameter with name "paramMap".

Is it possible to use the map in the jpql(hql) in the following manner?
(the query is simplified for the example but it captures the esence of my inquery)

**SELECT Invoice.id as key, :paramMap[Invoice.id] as value from Invoice Invoice**

Comment: No. You cannot.

Comment: do you want to map the query result to your HashMap?

Comment: No. I would like to reference values of the map parameter in the query.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use a map in JPQL (HQL) in the following manner?

No, it's not possible.